# What does a while loop do when used as while value!= 0?

Tags: solidity

This code is from the strings library. I believe while loop works like for loop when used like this while j < 10 ; { ...} how does it work when used like this while value!= 0 { ... }

```
      // Inspired by OraclizeAPI's implementation - MIT Licence
      // https://github.com/oraclize/ethereum-api/blob/b42146b063c7d6ee1358846c198246239e9360e8/oraclizeAPI_0.4.25.sol

      if (value == 0) {
          return "0";
      }
      uint256 temp = value;
      uint256 digits;
      while (temp != 0) {
          digits++;
          temp /= 10;
      }
      bytes memory buffer = new bytes(digits);
      while (value != 0) {
          digits -= 1;
          buffer[digits] = bytes1(uint8(48 + uint256(value % 10)));
          value /= 10;
      }
      return string(buffer);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On each iteration the condition of the `while` loop is evaluated again. Inside the `while` loop `value` is update (`value /= 10`) and at some point will become `0`. In this case the `while` loop will not be entered again and instead execute the next statement (`return string(buffer);`)

Solidity follows the general C-Semantics for loops, so if you require more information on how loops in Solidity work you can look at C-Language tutorials, such as https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/c-do-while-loops